# Unexpected output from URLEncoder in Java

Tags: java, android, encoding

I am trying to encode a URL parameter.

For example when I am encoding

> qOddENxeLxL+13drGKYUgA==\n

using [URL Encoder tool](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/)

It gives the following output which works when I request API

> qOddENxeLxL%2B13drGKYUgA%3D%3D%5Cn

But when I am encoding URL from my Java code (Android) using `URLEncoder.encode("qOddENxeLxL+13drGKYUgA==\n", "UTF-8");`

It gives me the following result

> qOddENxeLxL%252B13drGKYUgA%253D%253D%250A

I tried using other Encoding schemes too but could not produce the same result.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because the `\n` is being interpreted as a new line character. Java will treat `\` inside a string as starting an [escape sequence](https://web.archive.org/web/20110825073447/http://ehis.ebscohost.com.mms02.cerritos.edu/jwilson/java_language_resources/Java_Escape_Sequences.htm).
You have to escape it in order to get the same thing as in the URL you provided.

```
System.out.println(URLEncoder.encode("qOddENxeLxL+13drGKYUgA==\\n", "UTF-8"));
```

This will provide the same result:

```
qOddENxeLxL%2B13drGKYUgA%3D%3D%5Cn
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are feeding `\n` to the URLEncoder tool, which doesn't understand it as an escape sequence and so gives you `%5Cn`, and to the Java compiler inside a string literal, which does understand it and so gives you `0x0A`.

Answer (score -1):

Figured out the issue, here string was getting encoded two times.

While passing parameter to Retrofit call it is getting encoded automatically by retrofit and I was passing encoded parameter to retrofit so it got encoded again.

BTW thanks for the explanations. :)

Comment: No. If that was the issue you would have no `%` characters and multiple `%25` characters.

Comment: yes there are multiple %25 in qOddENxeLxL%252B13drGKYUgA%253D%253D%250A